# identicon glitch?

Tags: bug

The identicon that appears at the top of the questions page and on my profile changed yesterday, but strangely, the identicon that appears on the edit screen as a recent editor remains the way it was. To be clear, I see my both my old and recent posts and edits tagged with the old identicon, but a different one is at the top of my screen.

Edit: the green one that is by my name in this post is the old one, The new one is being displayed at the top of my screen.

There have been several similar posts, but no explanations given in any of them that I have found.

1. Does this continue indefinitely, or does it sync up eventually?
2. Does anyone else see my newer identicon (pink) anywhere?
3. How widespread is this glitch?
4. Would uploading a custom graphic help others? Personally, I don't care one way or another if it isn't confusing to others.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of my question. (Btw, my question has not been answered or resolved.) This question is showing that the problem has got worse not better. The volunteer posters on here deserve a resolution of this problem. The four question asked here are not asked on my original question.

Comment: Should be a dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different/283656#283656). Marc Gravell (SE employee I think) is on it.